# Wierd connectivity problems

Tags: networking, connection, windows-server-2003, ping

I'm having some quite confusing problems with the network.

First of all, all of the computers can access the internet and mapped drives and so on, the server can ping any LAN computers IP, the computers can ping the server LAN.

1. The server cannot ping web addresses such as Google,
2. The computers cannot ping web addresses such as Google,
3. The computers cannot ping each other

How can I be connected to the web and all network drives but not communicate with any other computer or ping the web?

Comment: It is possible your router is blocking the ICMP protocol. Have you checked this through its GUI?

Comment: I'm struggling why you think not having a PING return means connectivity problems. This question reads like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), can you explain what the problem actually is

Comment: Have you checked your DNS settings ? Can you resolve host names within and out of your your local network?